# GWTP Presenter prepareFromRequest - load data into form retrieved from event

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have been trying GWTP for the past couple of weeks and building a small project with it.

Here's the question :

I have a grid widget (attached screenshot) which shows a list of data.  On selection of a checkbox of a row and clicking on `Edit Request`, I get into a detail page.  [image: Summary Page]

Since I have all the data (model) to be shown in the detail page in the summary screen presenter itself, I don't want to fetch it from the database again.

So, I did the following :

1. On selection and clicking edit request, I get the selected model
2. Make a place request to the detail page
3. Fire an `edit event` and pass the selected model as parameter.

I understand that I am doing it wrong because when I select an item and hit `Edit Request`, the detail page does not receive the selected item yet. It just shows a *blank page* with no data filled in (obviously, because the place has been reached much before the event has been fired).

**Current code :**

```
RequestModel selectedItem = getView().getGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

PlaceRequest placeRequest=new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.initiationedit);  
getEventBus().fireEvent(new RequestEditEvent(selectedItem, PHASE_INITIATION));

placeManager.revealPlace(placeRequest);
```

**Personally thought solution** : Instead of firing an event, I could make a placerequest with a parameter of the selected item's `id` and then override the `useManualReveal` and the `prepareFromRequest` to fetch data fresh from database.

But is there a way I could avoid database call for the pre-existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to keep your current "RequestEditEvent" solution, then make sure to use `@ProxyEvent` (see http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Attaching_events_to_proxies).
2. Another possibility may be to invert the direction of the event: In your details presenter, fire an event which requests data from the overview presenter.
3. However, when using the same data across multiple presenters, then it may be a good idea to keep the data in a central model: Create a model class (@Singleton) and inject it everywhere you need it. Then you can make a lookup (by id) from that local model instead of asking the server. In this case, you don't need any events - just the id somewhere, e.g. as a place parameter, or even as a "currentItemId" in the model.

Comment: Spot on. I used the ProxyEvent and worked like a charm. For the sake of completeness, let me add the details too

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @Chris Lercher, I used the ProxyEvent. The implementation details are as follows.

In my `RequestEditPresenter` (the details presenter), I implemented the event handler `RequestEditHandler` as in

```
public class RequestEditPresenter extendsPresenter<RequestEditPresenter.MyView, RequestEditPresenter.MyProxy> implements RequestEditHandler{
```

then in the same `RequestEditPresenter` override the method in the `RequestEditHandler` as in

```
@Override
@ProxyEvent
public void onRequestEdit(RequestEditEvent event) {

    getView().setModelToView(event.getRequestModel());

    ...various other initiation process...

    placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.initiationedit));
}
```

Since the Details presenter was a `Place`, I used the placeManager. For presenters that do not have a `NameToken`, just call the `forceReveal()` method